# Как восстановить данные с жесткого диска

Tags: linux, windows, диск, windows-xp, manjaro

На моем ноуте стоят две системы:

- Windows XP
- и Linux Manjaro

Мне надо было отформатировать флешку,а я случайно начал форматировать жесткий диск на котором стояла Windows, а на ней у меня были важные данные.

Как я увидел что форматируется диск с виндой, сразу вырубил ноутбук.
Попробовал загрузить винду, но при загрузке выдалась ошибку что диску конец.
Как восстановить Windows на линуксе?
Линукс у меня на внешнем жестком диске

Comment: Надо восстанавливать не винду, а файлы. Любой программой для восстановления. Может быть, что-то и найдется.

Comment: Можно конкретнее? `Выдала ошибку что диску конец` - диск повреждён или просто система не может найти свой загрузчик?

Comment: Можете попробовать пройтись программой для восстановления, как сказал @Эникейщик, но такие программы хорошо восстанавливают бинарные файлы (фото, видео), есть шанс, что найдуться документы, но в таком случае, скорее всего граница файлов будет нарушена и их придётся частично восстанавливать в ручную. Также это сработает, только если вы не записывали на диск новых данных (в таком случае они просто перепишут собой старые). Также, если вы запустили полное форматирование диска - оно постепенно заменяет все на 0. Но раз форматирование не завершено, наверно 0 записался не везде.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> при загрузке выдалась ошибку что диску конец.

Если под этим Вы имеете в виду невозможность загрузки с винта, то действовать нужно так:

1. Берём любой LiveCD или флэшку
2. Загружаемся с него
3. Запускаем любой редактор разделов (например - GPatred) и смотрим состояние разделов.
4. Восстанавливаем виндовозные разделы - как было.
5. Восстанавливаем загрузчик

Ну а далее - в зависимости от тяжести поврежедений..

Comment: Вот зашел на том же ноутбуке, только с линукса https://yadi.sk/i/VzytZQpEMGj5Fg. Это как раз тот диск на котором стояла винда

Comment: Да и видимо я отформатировал только один раздел(загрузочный наверное) в Fat

Answer (score 2):

Вытаскиваем винт и подключаем к другому компу. Там используем следующие программы:

- WinHEX
- Active Undelete
- R-Studio.